# Parameters for training a sentence-similarity model using Bert?

Tags: performance, nlp, bert-language-model, cosine-similarity, sentence-similarity

I have a list of sentences :

```
sentences = ["Missing Plate", "Plate not found"]
```

I am trying to find the most similar sentences in the list by using Transformers model with [Huggingface embedding](https://huggingface.co/sentence-transformers/paraphrase-MiniLM-L6-v2). I am able to find the similar sentences but the model is still not able to identify the difference between :

```
"Message ID exists"  
"Message ID doesn't exist"
```

[Note: I am trying to find the similarity by using the [Cosine similarity](https://www.sbert.net/docs/package_reference/util.html#sentence_transformers.util.cos_sim) from pytorch]

Can you suggest me ways to hyperparameter tune my model so that the model can weigh in more on the negative words and consider them opposite?

I found the [list of parameters that can be tuned](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.20.1/en/main_classes/trainer#transformers.TrainingArguments) but not sure what the best parameters would be

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One major short-coming of BERT and other transformer variants is their inability to handle negation. Here is an excerpt from the paper **[What BERT Is Not: Lessons from a New Suite of Psycholinguistic
Diagnostics for Language Models:](https://aclanthology.org/2020.tacl-1.3.pdf)**

> Most strikingly, however, we find that BERT fails completely to show
> generalizable understanding of negation, raising questions about the
> aptitude of LMs to learn this type of meaning.

This phenomena can easily be observed by interacting with the BERT inference API on the [hugging face model hub](https://huggingface.co/bert-base-uncased?text=A%20hammer%20is%20not%20an%20%5BMASK%5D.). You can experiment with the following sentences:

```
A hammer is an [MASK].
A hammer is not an [MASK].
```

For both the cases, the highest scoring token is `object`, despite the explicit negation in the second case.

Therefore, I don't believe that further fine-tuning or hyper-parameter tuning will help in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :)
Is there any other way I can achieve this task? My dataset is not very big so I won't be able to train a model by myself, but resource consumption is not an issue. Any special kind of embeddings specially for identifying negations?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use sentence transformers which uses bert model:
first install the package:
`pip install sentence-transformers`

then

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer

sentences = ["This is an example sentence", "Each sentence is converted"]
model = SentenceTransformer("sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2")
embeddings = model.encode(sentences)
```

Now you can compare embeddings with cosine similarity.
For more information about this model visit this [link](https://huggingface.co/sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2)